# Connecting Outlet to Constraint in Custom View Instantiated from xib File Results in Crash

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, interface-builder, xib

I have a custom UIView subclass, whose layout is defined in a .xib file.

I create instaces with a class method that loads the xib from the app's bundle, like this:

```
class CustomTitleView: UIView
{
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var infoButton: UIButton!

    class func instance() -> CustomTitleView
    {
        return UINib(nibName: "CustomTitleView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! CustomTitleView
    }
}
```

This code works as expected. I use this view as a custom navigation title in a view controller.

The xib has autolayout constraints to:

- Center the label horizontally and vertically in its superview,
- Center the button vertically with respect to the label,
- Fix the horizontal space between the label and the button.

Next, I wish to put a `width` constraint to the label, and connect it to an outlet in the above code so that I can control it at runtime (to deal with truncation of text too long, etc.).

The xib's File Owner is set to my custom class.
I connect a "New Referencing Outlet" from the width constraint to a new outlet in my class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var widthConstraint:NSAutolayoutConstraint!
```

When I run my code, it crashes at this line:

```
return UINib(nibName: "CustomTitleView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! CustomTitleView
```

with the error:

> This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key widthConstraint

**What am I missing?**

---

**Note:** None of the following helped

- Clean build folder and rebuild.
- Disconnect outlet and reconnect.
- Connect outlet to another (existing) constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The only weird thing I see is using **NSAutoLayoutConstraint** instead of **NSLayoutConstraint**.